# Using an SQL query builder library/framework with Android

Tags: android, sql, external, querydsl

I am currently working on an Android project and will have to manage database connection and queries to store data. I will not be working with SQLite as provided by the Android device and using it is not an option.

As I need to build quite a lot of queries I wanted to use a library or framework to make the task easier. Looking at what was available, it seemed easiest to use a framework such as, for example, QueryDSL.

However, since I am working on Android, I am not sure if the framework is usable and what using it would entail. Does somebody have experience using an external database with Android and have any recommendations?

Comment: Did you try Querydsl SQL with Android? It should be quite easy to verify if it works.

Comment: @Timo No I did not. I have too little experience with said framework to judge by myself it it would work and especially what the overhead would be. For example, I am unsure how a _generated-sources_ folder would be handled or generated by Android. When looking at the documentation, it seems to be very broad and thus hard to determine if it is usable for my specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to connect to an external database is to use a REST client.
See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13403507/android-rest-client)

Comment: That would introduce substantially more overhead than I could manage I believe. I wanted to keep it simple and localised. Nevertheless, thank you.