# calling Java EE web service from Android Application

Tags: android, web-services, jakarta-ee

I have never work with web services and I have to establish a web service between a Java EE server application and an Android client application.

My question is: what is the best way to consume a Java EE web service from an Android application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest implementing a REST based web service in your Java EE server.
You can then use `JSONObject` to consume this restful service.

An example for using the `JSONObject` with REST can be found in this post:
[Android Rest Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13403507/android-rest-client)

Or this video by google: http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html

Answer (score 1):

There is a [wiki page](https://github.com/CUTR-at-USF/SiriRestClient/wiki/Parsing-JSON-and-XML-on-Android) which describes how to parse XML REST services on Android. The general message is that you can't just use JAXB because [JAXB can't be made run on android](http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2012/05/jaxb-can-be-made-to-run-on-android/). I think right now you have to use the Java XML support to manually parse the XML REST service response.

I found this answer via [Using JAXB with Google Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461127/using-jaxb-with-google-android)