# How to send HTML emails with Mailgun on Android < 5.0

Tags: java, android, mailgun

I'm trying to integrate Mailgun into my Android application, but I'm running into a lot of issues, and was wondering if anyone who has successfully used Mailgun on Android can provide some help. I am able to send plain text emails following the Mailgun user manual (https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#sending-via-api), but only if the Android version of the device is at least Lollipop. Any device with a lower Android version, I receive many errors regarding missing XML-related classes, which I cannot resolve since I cannot import `javax.*` classes. The same happens when I try to send HTML email using the code outlined in the user guide.

Example of errors received in log:

```
The provider class, class com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$App, could not be instantiated.
Processing will continue but the class will not be utilized
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory not present 

The provider class, class com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$Text, could not be instantiated.
Processing will continue but the class will not be utilized                                                            
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory not present

The provider class, class com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General, could not be instantiated.
Processing will continue but the class will not be utilized                                                             
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory not present
```

Thus, I am wondering if anyone who has ran into these issues (using Mailgun on Android devices < 5.0 and/or sending HTML emails) and were able to solve them can give me some pointers. Thanks!

Comment: "I receive many errors regarding missing XML-related classes" -- you might wish to edit your question and provide details of what is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are pointing the official Mailgun documentation I assume you are using Jersey 1.x library as a JAX-RS client.

I suggest you give the 2.x branch a try. Take a look [at this](https://blogs.oracle.com/japod/entry/jersey_2_x_client_on).

Also, you are not required to use Jersey. Any REST client will do. In [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13403507/android-rest-client) you have alternative options and more information.

Now exactly into your problem. [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net) and any JAX-RS library uses *providers* for differents things including dealing with content (entities). It seems your problem is that the default XML entity provider uses JAXB or JAXP (those `javax.xml` classes) which is not available in your classpath. But [you can provide Jersey with any other entity manager for XML content type](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html). Actually, the current documentation explains [how to use MOXy as an alternate JAXB implementation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#d0e9211). It is even compiled as a dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Never occurred to be that I could use other REST clients haha... decided to go with Retrofit which worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [this library](https://github.com/sargue/mailgun).

Also you need to add 'configurations' to your gradle file and it should look like this:

```
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   compile 'net.sargue:mailgun:1.3.2'
}

configurations {
   compile.exclude group: 'javax.inject', module: 'javax.inject'
}
```

More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43707590/4576879)