# MailGun Android HttpUrlConnection constant error 400

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, mailgun, http-status-code-400

After a complete and utter failure to implement code with Retrofit, I have used Android's HttpURLConnection class to try and send an email through MailGun. However whatever I seem to do I get error 400 bad request back. I do not know what I am doing wrong - similar code seems to be working perfectly within iOS. The 4 lines commented out make no difference. Hardcoding the values for from and to did not fix it either. I have tried using application/json for Content-Type as well. Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated!

```
URL u = new URL("https://api.mailgun.net/v3/companyname.com/messages");
HttpURLConnection restConnection = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
restConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
String authHeader = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(apiKey.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
restConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authHeader);
restConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
restConnection.setRequestProperty("from", "Company Name <noreply@companyname.com>");
restConnection.setRequestProperty("to", "myemailaddress@gmail.com");
restConnection.setRequestProperty("subject", "test");
restConnection.setRequestProperty("text", "test");
//restConnection.setUseCaches(false);
//restConnection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
//restConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
//restConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
restConnection.connect();
int status = restConnection.getResponseCode();
```

Comment: have you tried the request separate from your code? does it returned correctly?

Comment: it's probably how you define your API, error 400 means your request paramaters couldn't be understand by the server

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String apiKey = "api:{key}"
String authHeader = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(apiKey.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    try {
        String data = URLEncoder.encode("from", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("from@from.com", "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("to", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("to@to.com", "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("subject", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("subject", "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("text", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("msg body", "UTF-8");
        URL u = new URL("https://api.mailgun.net/{DOMAIN}/messages");
        HttpURLConnection restConnection = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        restConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        restConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        restConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authHeader);
        OutputStreamWriter w = new OutputStreamWriter(restConnection.getOutputStream());
        w.write(data);
        w.flush();
        w.close();
        int status = restConnection.getResponseCode();

        // switch statement to catch HTTP 200 and 201 errors
        switch (status) {
            case 200:
                // live connection to your REST service is established here using getInputStream() method
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(restConnection.getInputStream()));

                // create a new string builder to store json data returned from the REST service
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                // loop through returned data line by line and append to stringbuilder 'sb' variable
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                br.close();

                // remember, you are storing the json as a stringy
                try {
                    json = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
                }
                // return JSON String containing data to Tweet activity (or whatever your activity is called!)
                break;
            case 400:
                Log.d(TAG, "Bad request");
                break;
            case 401:
                Log.d(TAG, "Unauthorized");
                break;
            case 402:
                Log.d(TAG, "Request Failed");
                break;
            case 404:
                Log.d(TAG, "404");
                break;
            case 500:
            case 502:
            case 503:
            case 504:
                Log.d(TAG, "Mailgun fail");
                break;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use MailGun on Android just do few steps:

1) Check [this library](https://github.com/sargue/mailgun). And implement it.

2) This library is for Java, not for Android. So you need to add 'configurations' to your gradle file and it should look like this:

```
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   compile 'net.sargue:mailgun:1.3.2'
}

configurations {
   compile.exclude group: 'javax.inject', module: 'javax.inject'
}
```

[more information here](https://github.com/sargue/mailgun/issues/12)

3) So now you can use this library: (don't forget to run it in background thread)

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
    .domain("somedomain.com")
    .apiKey("key-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
    .from("Test account", "postmaster@somedomain.com");
Response response = Mail.using(configuration)
    .to("marty@mcfly.com")
    .subject("This message has an text attachment")
    .text("Please find attached a file.")
    .multipart()
    .attachment(new File("/path/to/image.jpg"))
    .build()
    .send();
```